# Bookdown: ! LaTeX Error: Command \href undefined

Tags: latex, bookdown

While building a project using "bookdown" I encounter the following error.  Any suggestions?

! LaTeX Error: Command \href undefined.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile bookdown.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See bookdown.log for more info.
Execution halted
Error: bookdown::render_book() failed to render the output format 'bookdown::pdf_book'.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.

Comment: Are you loading the `hyperref` package? Can you add a [mre]?

Comment: You need to load `hyperref` like this: https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-crc/commit/683e5fbd87478240c84cbebaf04058dd685090c8 Without you providing a minimal reproducible example, we can't tell you exactly where to load this package.